# How can I use the bash <<< operator with diff?

Tags: bash, here-string

Please, observe:

```shellsession
$ diff <(echo a) <<<b
diff: missing operand after '/dev/fd/63'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
```

I know `<(...)` works fine:

```shellsession
$ diff <(echo a) <(echo b)
1c1
< a
---
> b
```

I also know `<<<` works fine in general:

```shellsession
$ cat <<<a
a
```

So what is the right way to call it with `diff`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `diff` command expects *filename* arguments, while the here string `<<<` writes to standard input. However `man diff` tells us

> If  a FILE is '-', read standard input.

So

```
$ diff <(echo a) - <<<b
1c1
< a
---
> b
```

The same would apply for a here *document*:

```
$ diff <(echo a) - << \EOF
b
EOF
1c1
< a
---
> b
```

Answer (score 11):

On systems that have `/dev/fd/x` devices, you can do:

```
diff /dev/fd/3 3<< EOF3 /dev/fd/4 4<< EOF4
some text
EOF3
some other text
EOF4
```

using the Bourne shell's `<<` here-document redirection operator.

```
diff /dev/fd/3 3<<< 'some text' /dev/fd/4 4<<< 'some other text'
```

Using zsh's `<<<` here-string redirection operator.

In zsh, you can also do:

```
diff <(<<<'some text') <(<<<'some other text')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `<()` with `cat <<<`:

```
diff <(echo a) <(cat <<<b)
```

Steeldriver's answer works well if you just need to use `<<<` for one argument, but if you need it for both this will work:

```
diff <(cat <<<a) <(cat <<<b)
```

But it's not clear why you would need a here-string for this. There's little difference between `<(cat <<<a)` and `<(echo a)`

Comment: I presume it's a simplified example.

Comment: Probably, but I can't think of a way that it could make a difference in a more complex example.